# Why does vector's random access iterator gives the same memory address unlike pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, iterator

```
vector<int>::iterator it;
for(it=v.begin();it<v.end();it++)
{
     cout <<&(it)<<" ";
     cout<<(*it)<<" ";
}
```

It outputs:

```
0x7fff6667cdf0 7 0x7fff6667cdf0 14 0x7fff6667cdf0 15 0x7fff6667cdf0 16
```

Note the address is same each time, the question is why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the address of the same object `it`, then you'll get the same address every time. The element pointed by the iterator changes, but the address of the iterator itself (`it` is an object and has its own address) won't change.

It's same for pointer variable too, if you're getting the address of the pointer itself. E.g.

```
int* p;
size_t s;
for (p = v.data(), s = 0; s < v.size(); s++, p++)
{
    cout <<&(p)<<" ";
    cout<<(*p)<<" ";
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand. p is incrementing right so why it's same?

Comment: @ProtoType The address pointed by the pointer changes, but the address of the pointer itself (the pointer is an object and has its own address) won't change.

Comment: Ohh! ok yes pointer itself has it's own address thanks @songyunanyao